# how can I modify my swift code so that it is being run in the background without blocking UI?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableViewController` and on each cell I have a `UIImageView`. This image view is populated with a snapshot of a video stored on a server. As for now my code looks as follows:

```
func tableView(detailsPanel: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = detailsPanel.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! DetailsCell

    let test:SingleTest =  self.items[indexPath.row] as! SingleTest

//this code hangs up the UI for each cell:
    do {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(string: test.video)!, options: nil)
        let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
        let uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: uiImage)
        cell.testPhoto.image = uiImage
    } catch  {
        print("Error generating thumbnail: \(error)")
    }

}
```

How can I modify my code so that everything in the `do catch` block does not block the UI and works in the background?

===EDIT

after following your advices I modified my code so that now the `do-catch` statement is surrounded by dispatch:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
    var uiImage = UIImage()
    do {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(string: test.video)!, options: nil)
        let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
        uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
        //let imageView = UIImageView(image: uiImage)
    } catch  {
        print("Error generating thumbnail: \(error)")
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        cell.testPhoto.image = uiImage
    }
}
```

now it seems to be working, but it does not cache the images and every time I scroll the table, it fetches the photos again... What's the best way to avoid it?

Comment: Did you try searching Stack Overflow? The business of how to provide table cell UI asynchronously has been _very_ thoroughly explained here.

Comment: @matt, I found some solutions that I tried by myself on my code, however it didn't work as expected :( I tried to surround this code with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in` but it didn't help, can you give me a hint of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user3766930 You use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{})` to update the UI from the background queue.

Comment: @boidkan ok, that's a good point, however in my case the blocking point is while fetching big photo from network - so how can I put it in the background and then update the ui when it's ready?

Comment: @user3766930 You can start by reading this https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch there is also plenty on SO to read.

Comment: Guys, can you check my edited question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough idea of how it can be done, the code probably will not work, but it gives you a start.

Initialize a queue within the class:

```
        let processQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "myQueue", attributes: [])
```

Dispatch the processing to this queue and dispatch back to main when done:

```
func tableView(detailsPanel: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = detailsPanel.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! DetailsCell

    let test:SingleTest =  self.items[indexPath.row] as! SingleTest

    processQueue.async {

        let image: CGImage?

        do {
            let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(string: test.video)!, options: nil)
            let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            image = try imgGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)

        } catch  {
            print("Error generating thumbnail: \(error)")
        }

        guard let cgImage = image else { return }

        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

            guard let `self` = self else { return }

            //TODO: perform some checking that current cell is still the intended cell

            let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            cell.testPhoto.image = uiImage

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this! Based on your answer I changed my code, however there is still one issue - can you please check the edit to my original question?